# Best practice for validating API input in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, validation, http, mobile

I am developing a mobile app, with the backend in Node.js. Users will interact with the platform almost exclusively through the mobile app. As part of the backend, I am exposing multiple APIs to be utilized by the mobile app -- for example: an API to create an account, send a message, post a picture, etc.

**What is best practice to validate the API input?**

My thought is to create a module for each API, whose purpose is to extract, sanitize, and validate the relevant attributes from the http-request. For example, the "create an account" API will have an associated `AccountCreationRequest` module with a `validate` method in which all account-creation-specific validations will be defined. Each specific validation can then be performed by libraries such as [**express validator**](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator) and [**validator**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator).

```
exports.AccountCreationRequest = {

  init: function(request) {
    ... extract attributes ...
  },

  sanitizeAndValidate: function() {
    ... use express-validator/validator on
    attributes such as username, email, etc ...
  }, 

  isValid: function() {
    ... return result of validation ...
  }
};
```

Then, when the backend API receives a request,

```
var accountCreationRequest = AccountCreationRequest.init(httpRequest);
accountCreationRequest.sanitizeAndValidate();

if (accountCreationRequest.isValid()) {
  ... store in database and notify client of success ...            
} else {
  ... notify client of failure ...
}
```

My concern is that N APIs will require N request-validation-modules. However, since each API is unique, I don't think there is much opportunity for code reuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use express, you can do something like

```
app.use('/private', function(req, res, next) {
    if (/*some condition to check for authentication*/) {
       next();
    } else { //unauthorized
       res.status(401).send('not authorized, please authenticate');
    }
});
```

that will filter everything under the /private path through your authentication condition. You can also use wildcards in the path if you prefer.